# Biblatex custom cite command only in footnote

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, footnotes, biber

I dont like the citations in moste presentations. If you wanna look up a special reference, you most likely forgot the number when de reference are shown at the end. Therefor i made a custom citation command `\mycite`, acting like cite, but adding some brief informations in the footnote (without footnote index). Sometimes i just want to add a reference to the whole frame, without any explicit reference in the text, therefor i made a second command `\myframecite`. But on the latter one i have some dificulties, because it adds some empty space in the text, while it should only operate on the footnote.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
    @article{Doe2013,
        title   = {Lorem Ipsum},
        volume  = {1},
        journal = {J. Foo},
        author  = {J. Doe},
        year    = {2013},
        pages   = {1--10},
    }
    @article{Public2013,
        title   = {Dolor Sit Amet},
        volume  = {1},
        journal = {J. Foo},
        author  = {J. Q. Public},
        year    = {2013},
        pages   = {11--20},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{myframecite}{%
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\scriptsize##1}%
  \footnotetext{%
    \blxmkbibnote{foot}{%
      \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}%
      \addspace%
      \printnames{author}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
      \printfield{title}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
      \printfield{year}%
}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myframecite}%
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{myframecite}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\cite{#1} \myframecite{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\mycite{Doe2013}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\myframecite{Public2013}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The small example produces the following frame:
[image: output]

**I dont want the empty line between the third and fourth definition, but i have no clue how to get rid of it.** Of course, i could put the `\myframecite` command at the end of the frame, where the emply line wouldn't be that disturbing. Nevertheless, the additional empty line results in an odd (asymmetric) spacing, which i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all `\cite` commands defined with `\DeclareCiteCommand` assume that they print something where they are used. So they issue a lot of `\leavevmode` commands in order to avoid messing with vertical space. Ironically, these prevention measures actually cause unwanted vertical space here.

The only way I could find to get rid of the unwanted space for good is via a short wrapper that simply removes the `\leavevmode`s that `biblatex` would normally issue. It's not pretty, but it works here.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{myframecite}{%
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\scriptsize##1}%
  \mkbibfootnotetext{%
    \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printnames{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \printfield{title}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \printfield{year}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myframecite@i}%
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{myframecite}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand*{\myframecite}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \def\blx@leavevmode@cite{}%
  \def\blx@leavevmode{}%
  \myframecite@i{#1}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\cite{#1}\myframecite{#1}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\mycite{sigfridsson}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\myframecite{worman}
\begin{definition}test\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Slide without excessive vertical space.]

Comment: It works as intended, thank you!